# Show that a defined Linear Map is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone help me run through the process of how to show if a defined linear map is linear?

The exercise I have:

Show that the map L: $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$L\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 + x_2 \\ x_1 - x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$
is linear where $x_1$, $x_2$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$

I understand that in order for the map to be linear

$L(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha L(x) + \beta L(y) $

but how can I show that?

Comment: Substitute (coordinatized form of) $\alpha x+\beta y$ in the place of $\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$.

Comment: What is $L(\alpha x+\beta y)$?. What is $L(x)$ and $L(y)$? Try to compute both sides and show that are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_{1},x_{2}),y=(y_{1},y_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
\begin{align*} 
\alpha L(x)+\beta L(y)&=\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}+x_{2}\\ 
x_{1}-x_{2}
\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}+y_{2}\\ 
y_{1}-y_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha x_{1}+\alpha x_{2} +\beta y_{1}+\beta y_{2}\\ 
\alpha x_{1}-\alpha x_{2} +\beta y_{1}-\beta y_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=L((\alpha x_{1}+\beta y_{1},\alpha x_{2}+\beta y_{2}))\\
&=L((\alpha x_{1},\alpha x_{2})+(\beta y_{1},\beta y_{2}))\\
&=L(\alpha x +\beta y).
\end{align*}